# ideal generated by irreducible polynomial

Tags: ring-theory

If $p(x)\in F[x]$ be a irreducible polynomial over $F$, what are the elements of $(p(x))$?

From my book

> $(a) = \{ ra|r \in R\}$

but I don't know what $r$ is going to be in this case.

I see this a lot in other theorems like

> If $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $F[x]$ of degree $n\ge 1$, and is irreducible over $F$, there is extension $E$ of $F$ such that $[E:F] = n$ where $p(x)$ has a root.

here on this theorem proof, it begins with

> Let $F[x]$ be ring of polynomials in $x$ over $F$ and let $V=(p(x))$ be an ideal of $F[x]$ generated by $p(x)$ ... and goes on and on.

I have difficulty understanding the proof of this theorem from the very beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r$ is just an element of the ring $R$ - which in your question is the polynomial ring $F[x]$. So in this case (putting $a=p(x)$ and $r = f(x)$ for some $f(x) \in F[x]$), we have:

$$(p(x)) = \left\{f(x)p(x) \mid f(x) \in F[x] \right\}$$

Equivalently, if $g(x) = f(x)p(x)$ for some $f(x) \in F[x]$, what can you say about $g(x)$?